# Как применить анимированный border

Tags: html, css, css-animation

Помогите  применить к этому классу: 
`.post-38435.post img {}` (это картинка к конкретному посту)
вот этот анимированный border  (https://codepen.io/mike-schultz/pen/NgQvGO)

Заранее премного благодарен.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Постоянная анимация градиента**

Анимируется атрибут линейного градиента `stop-color`

Цвета градиента можете подобрать по своему вкусу в атрибуте анимации `values="violet;blue;violet"`

```css
.container {
width:50%;
height:50%;
}
#rec1 {
fill:transparent;
stroke-width:3;
stroke:url(#linearGradient);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 237 113" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" >
 <defs>
  <linearGradient id="linearGradient" x1="-36" x2="200" y1="148" y2="148" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
   <stop style="stop-color:violet" offset="0">
    <animate 
  attributeName="stop-color"
  dur="1.5s"
  values="violet;blue;violet"
  repeatCount="indefinite"  />
   </stop>
   <stop style="stop-color:blue" offset="0.8">
     <animate attributeName="stop-color"
  dur="1.5s" 
  values="blue;orange;blue"
  repeatCount="indefinite"  />
   </stop>
    <stop style="stop-color:orange" offset="1">
     <animate 
   attributeName="stop-color" 
   dur="1.5s"
   values="orange;violet;orange" 
   repeatCount="indefinite" />
    </stop>
  
  </linearGradient>
 </defs>
 <g id="rec" 
   transform="translate(36 -91)"
 >
  <rect id="rec1"
   x="-35" y="93"
   width="234" height="110" ry="18"
 </g>
</svg>
</div>
```

**Анимация по клику на объекте**

```css
.container {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
}
#rec1 {
fill: transparent;
stroke-width:2;
stroke:url(#linearGradient);
}
#txt1 {
font-size:48px;
fill: url(#linearGradient);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <svg version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 237 113" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
 <defs>
  <linearGradient id="linearGradient" x1="-36" x2="200" y1="148" y2="148" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
   <stop style="stop-color:violet" offset="0">
    <animate 
     attributeName="stop-color" 
  dur="0.8s" 
  values="violet;blue;violet" 
  begin="rec.click" 
  repeatCount="2"
 />
   </stop>
    <stop style="stop-color:blue" offset="0.8">
     <animate 
  attributeName="stop-color"
  dur="1.0s"
  values="blue;orange;blue" 
  begin="rec.click" 
  repeatCount="2"
 />
   </stop>
    <stop style="stop-color:orange" offset="1">
    <animate 
  attributeName="stop-color" 
  dur="1.5s" 
  values="orange;violet;orange"
  begin="rec.click" 
  repeatCount="2"
    />
   </stop>
  
  </linearGradient>
 </defs>
 <g id="rec" transform="translate(36 -91)">
  <rect id="rec1" x="-35" y="93" width="234" height="110" ry="18" />
   <text id="txt1" x="0" y="158"  >Click me</text>
 </g>
</svg>
</div>
```

Если текст анимировать не надо,- уберите строку из кода

`<text x="0" y="158" font-size="48" fill="url(#linearGradient)" >Click me</text>`

### Update

SVG код отформатировал столбиком, для более лёгкого восприятия

Answer (score 2):

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:200');
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  background: #1D1F20;
}

#box {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Raleway';
  font-size: 2.5rem;
}

.post-38435.post img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: var(--borderWidth);
}

.post-38435.post {
  --borderWidth: 3px;
  background: #1D1F20;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: var(--borderWidth);
}

.post-38435.post:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(-1 * var(--borderWidth));
  left: calc(-1 * var(--borderWidth));
  height: calc(100% + var(--borderWidth) * 2);
  width: calc(100% + var(--borderWidth) * 2);
  background: linear-gradient(60deg, #f79533, #f37055, #ef4e7b, #a166ab, #5073b8, #1098ad, #07b39b, #6fba82);
  border-radius: calc(2 * var(--borderWidth));
  z-index: -1;
  animation: animatedgradient 3s ease alternate infinite;
  background-size: 300% 300%;
}

@keyframes animatedgradient {
  0% {
    background-position: 0% 50%;
  }
  50% {
    background-position: 100% 50%;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 0% 50%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="post post-38435" id="box">
  <img src="http://bass-sklep.pl/uploads/picture/pl_PL/840b0670c3e1b8eefeaea0166371dc37.jpg" />
</div>
```

Что тут тяжело ?